# units check for horsepower to weight (Hp/W)

Tags: unit

is this units breakdown correct:

Hp/W= (ft*lb/s) / (lb*ft/s^-2) = s^-1?

I think I might made mistake?

Comment: using horsepower, the units will be HP/pound or hp/ton most likely.  Hp has a conversion factor in it, 33000 ft-lb/min/HP.

Comment: By W you do mean Watts don't you?

Answer (score 1):

You are confused by the units ($lb_m$ - a unit of mass; $lb_f$ - a unit of force). As a matter of force, the units for horsepower is $\dfrac{ft-lb_f}{s}$, and the units for weight (m*g) is $lb_f$. So the resulting units is $ft/s$. This article may clear your confusion. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_(force)#:~:text=The%20international%20standard%20symbol%20for%20the%20pound%20as,mass%20exerts%20one%20pound%20force%20due%20to%20gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_(force)#:%7E:text=The%20international%20standard%20symbol%20for%20the%20pound%20as,mass%20exerts%20one%20pound%20force%20due%20to%20gravity).

**ADD:**

**Hp/W = (ftlb/s) / (lbft/s^-2)** = $\dfrac{ft-lb_f}{s}$/$\dfrac{lb_m ft}{s^2}$ = $\dfrac{ft-lb_f}{s}/lb_f$

**Note:** $\dfrac{lb_m ft}{s^2}$ = $lb_m*\dfrac{ft}{s^2}$ = $m*a$ = $F$, or = $m*g$ = $W$

Answer (score 0):

Horsepower over weight is fundamentally Power over Force. Since, a common formula connecting Power and force is:

$$ P = F\cdot v$$

where

- P is the Power
- F is force
- v is velocity

you can obtain from the above, that the units of $P\over F $ are equal to the units of velocity i.e. **Units of length over time**